# Flushing Docker image cache in Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

We are using gitlab-ci to build our docker images for Kubernetes. The source images are locally cached and I can see that in `describe pod runner-XXXX`:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                                             Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                                             -------
  Normal  Scheduled              2m    default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned runner-8834f94f-project-7648852-concurrent-097bbx to gke-testing-preempt-pool-82e6cfcc-6129
  ...
  Normal  Pulled                 2m    kubelet, gke-testing-preempt-pool-82e6cfcc-6129  Container image "maven:alpine" already present on machine
```

Note the: `Container image "maven:alpine" already present on machine`.

This is great because it saves transferred data. But what should I do if I want to flush this cache and force redownloading of the image?

Comment: I don't know if its more related to gitlab-ci or docker... But you can [disable cache of gitlab-runner for a specific job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/caching/index.html#disabling-cache-on-specific-jobs) or maybe this one will help you better : [Using the always pull policy with docker executor on GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#using-the-always-pull-policy). The second might be more helpful than the fist resource.